# How to isolate parsing results with only one to two digits in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In continuing my FreshDirect program I'm looking to get the values of the quantity I have in my Standing Orders. I need to get these values in order to eventually automate the ordering process but for now this is what I'm stuck on. Is there a way to get only the values of the quantities of the items?

What I've tried to do is parse through the "input" tags in the HTML. Then I used re.sub to try to isolate the digits. I'm still getting a whole bunch of values including letters. For reference, the HTML I'm looking to parse looks like this:

```
<input id="qty_cartline_change_-1313013247" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">
```

```
def get_values():
    for items in inputs:
        standing_order_value = str(items.get('value'))
        print(standing_order_value)
        for node in standing_order_value:
            re.sub(r'\D', '', node)
        current_value = {'Quantity':standing_order_value}
        print(current_value)
```

I expect it to just grab the number next to "value=" (which would be 1)
for all of the items I have in the inventory. Now I am able to get those numbers but I also get a whole lot of extra co`enter code here`ntent and I'm not sure why.

```
What I get that is good: 1
{'Quantity': '1'}
1
{'Quantity': '1'}
1
{'Quantity': '1'}
1
{'Quantity': '1'}
1
{'Quantity': '1'}
1
{'Quantity': '1'}
1
```

```
What I get that I don't want: 
atc_a200237b-8c88-4611-8582-3d8dd3eba7c5
{'Quantity': 'atc_a200237b-8c88-4611-8582-3d8dd3eba7c5'}
gro_pid_4010985
{'Quantity': 'gro_pid_4010985'}
/pdp.jsp?productId=gro_pid_4010985&catId=gro_snack_nubars&variantId=dyf_scr_ord1
{'Quantity': '/pdp.jsp?productId=gro_pid_4010985&catId=gro_snack_nubars&variantId=dyf_scr_ord1'}
gro_snack_nubars
{'Quantity': 'gro_snack_nubars'}
dyf_scr_ord1
{'Quantity': 'dyf_scr_ord1'}
GRO4010985
{'Quantity': 'GRO4010985'}
EA
{'Quantity': 'EA'}
EA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use BeautifulSoup you can use attribute = value selectors

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'lxml')
values = [item['value'] for item in soup.select("input[value]")]
```

---

You can look at which combination of selectors gives the best results. Above I added `value` attribute to ensure `input` tag has a `value` attribute but it is likely you could use the following to ensure it is a quantity `input` tag. You could assume there is a `value` attribute.

```
values = [item['value'] for item in soup.select("input[data-productdata-name=quantity]")]
```

Without assuming there is a `value` attribute and specifying there must be:

```
values = [item['value'] for item in soup.select("input[value][data-productdata-name=quantity]")]
```

That may be the most reliable.

---

If you are certain that the `productdata-name=quantity` attribute = value pair only occurs for quantity input values with value attributes then it will be faster to do:

```
values = [item['value'] for item in soup.select("[data-productdata-name=quantity]")]
```

---

The singular, first match version is:

```
value = soup.select_one("[data-productdata-name=quantity]")['value']
```

---

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<input id="qty_cartline_change_-1313013247" class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1" maxlength="4" data-component="quantitybox.value" data-productdata-name="quantity">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
values = [item['value'] for item in soup.select("input[value]")]
print(values)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement this solution and see what comes of it. Again, thank you.

Comment: Done. Yes this answer is good and is putting me on the right track for sure. Thank you.